# Occurrence rate $20/h$, $t=0.25h$ What is the chance to exactly $5$ Occurrences in that $t$?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

I have a question in my homework:

Time interval: $1$ Hour

Divide that time to $4$ Equal periods, without overlap, each period $15$ Mins long.

If in that interval, there are $20$ Occurrences of the event, what is the probability that in each $15$ Mins occurs exactly $5$ Events.

---

My try:
It seems to me like poisson distribution, with $\lambda = 20$ And $t = 0.25$ Therefore: $\lambda t = 5$.

Therefore i should get:

$$
P(i = 5) = exp(-\lambda t) \frac{(\lambda t)^i}{i!} = exp(-5) \frac{5^5}{5!} = 0.175
$$

Yet, i have options to the answer, none of them is my answer.

What did i do wrong?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Straight combinatorics:

Probability

$$= \frac{N\text{(umerator)}}{D\text{(enominator)}} $$

with

$$D = 4^{(20)}.$$

How many ways are there of selecting 5 events for each time period.

$$N = \binom{20}{5}\binom{15}{5}\binom{10}{5}.$$

Final answer:

$$\frac{N}{D}.$$

Comment: Can you explain why its $D = 4^{20}$?

Comment: @Alon If there was only 1 event, there would be exactly 4 possibilities re which interval it occurred in.  With two events there are $4 \times 4$ possibilities.  With 3 events, $4\times 4\times 4$ possibilities.  And so forth.